# Looking at neighbouring nodes, n nodes ahead

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a project where i am implementing a heuristic for "online" network optimization in Java. The Heuristic is meant to be dynamic and depending on a time limit, i will be looking on N nodes to decide which way to go. My problem is the following:

From the node i'm currently in, i want to look at the neighboring nodes to decide which way is the best to go at the moment. I also want to look at the neighboring nodes of my current nodes neighbors, i want to do this N times(if N is three i want to look at neighbors and their neighbors and then their neighbors). Looking N neighboring nodes ahead i want to add the first node (of the best route) to the path, then repeat the proceeder.

Is there an efficient way of doing this, I realize that the problem can be solved if i write the code with a static N, but I need this to be changeable.

I hope I explained the problem clear enough, is there anyone who has a smart solution for this problem.

Comment: So what have you tried? Sounds like an extension of BFS

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by using Recursion.

```
'public ArrayList <path> searchNetwork(int Depth, ArrayList<Path> paths, int currentDepth){
    currentDepth++
if(currentDepth < depth){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        if(paths.get(i).getNeighbours > 1){
        paths.add(createNewPath(paths.get(i).deepCopy));
        paths.get(i).addNeighbour;
        }
    }
    searchNetwork(deoth, paths, currentDepth);
}
```

}`